# What is the glowing orb over the focus bar?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

I might have missed the particular tutorial.

What is the significance of the glowing blue-white orb of light over the focus bar?

Comment: are you on PC? can you post a screen shot of what you're talking about?

Comment: Sure, will try to remember to capture one next time I see it (trouble is, gameplay (as opposed to UI itself) really tends to capture my attention, and I'm not sure when this appears, so might take a while).

Comment: Not entirely sure (so not answer), but this might be your focus recharging from an action you performed. I have focus regained on stealth kill from a rune, and when I perform a stealth kill I see a white orb around my focus bar, don't remember exactly where.